# BGP ASN design - advertise different prefixes from different locations in same AS

Tags: bgp

Is there potential for issues when advertising different prefixes from different locations but in same AS?

Router 'A' in New York will advertise prefix x.x.x.x/24 and Router 'B' in London will advertise y.y.y.y/24.

Both of the routers will exist in the same AS(AS 100). They will not maintain an iBGP peering with each other(see attached diagram).

[bgp topo diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnOlK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is called BGP Anycast and as long as you offer the EXACT same services on both sides there is nothing (BGP wise) again such designs. Just be aware that your hosts on those network should use other (unique to the site) IPs when they connect outside because the answer could go back to the other site.

Pros, cons and more information can be found in this Article on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast